# Spring - Multiple Profiles active

Tags: java, spring

I basically have a bean in Spring that I wanted to activate only when 2 profiles are active. Basically, it would be like:

```
@Profile({"Tomcat", "Linux"})
public class AppConfigMongodbLinux{...}

@Profile({"Tomcat", "WindowsLocal"})
public class AppConfigMongodbWindowsLocal{...}
```

So I'd like that when I use `-Dspring.profiles.active=Tomcat,WindowsLocal`, it would try to use only the `AppConfigMongodbWindowsLocal`, but it still tries to register the `AppConfigMongodbLinux`.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfigMongodbLinux': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
```

Is it possible to make the bean be registerd only when both profiles are active or am I using it incorrectly? :)

Thanks!!

---

Edit: Posting the full stack.

The error is actually on a property that is missing on the properties, but will this bean get activated? I wanted to understand this to ensure I'm not activating a wrong bean..

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfigMongodbLinux': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.Integer mycompany.config.AppConfigMongodbLinux.mongoPort; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongo.port' in string value "${mongo.port}"
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.Integer mycompany.config.AppConfigMongodbLinux.mongoPort; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongo.port' in string value "${mongo.port}"
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongo.port' in string value "${mongo.port}"
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with the profiles. Check if the autowired beans in appConfigMongodbLinux are available. Post full stack trace.

Comment: @ShankarPS It does look like a problem with the profiles. A configuration file that he doesn't want to activate is looking for a property not available in that configuration.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately, `@Profile` activates if *any* listed profile is active. There are a couple of ways around this.

- Apply the common `@Profile("Tomcat")` annotation to a top-level configuration class, and then apply `@Profile("Windows")` to a nested configuration class (or `@Bean` method).
- If Spring Boot is acceptable as a dependency, use [`@AllNestedConditions`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/AllNestedConditions.html) to create an annotation that's the AND instead of the OR.

It looks like what you're trying to do would be clean to write if you were using Spring Boot autoconfiguration classes; if it's practical to introduce autoconfiguration at this stage of your application's lifecycle, I recommend considering it.

Comment: Or a condition implementation like https://gist.github.com/zapl/1262d21b8866ebc61e48ece505277f69 derived from `@Profile`

Comment: I do use SpringBoot! I'll take a look on the annotation you said, but It makes a lot of sense the first option too.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 47):

**Spring version 5.1** and above offers additional functionality for specifying more complex profile string expressions. In your case desired functionality can be achieved in the following way:

```
@Profile({"Tomcat & Linux"})
@Configuration
public class AppConfigMongodbLinux {...}
```

Please read [Using @Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-java) chapter from Spring reference documentation for more info.

Update (method level profile expressions):
Actually I've tested some @Bean method level profile expressions and everything works like a charm:

```
/**
 * Shows basic usage of {@link Profile} annotations applied on method level.
 */
@Configuration
public class MethodLevelProfileConfiguration {

    /**
     * Point in time related to application startup.
     */
    @Profile("qa")
    @Bean
    public Instant startupInstant() {
        return Instant.now();
    }

    /**
     * Point in time related to scheduled shutdown of the application.
     */
    @Bean
    public Instant shutdownInstant() {
        return Instant.MAX;
    }

    /**
     * Point in time of 1970 year.
     */
    @Profile("develop & production")
    @Bean
    public Instant epochInstant() {
        return Instant.EPOCH;
    }
}
```

Integration tests:

```
/**
 * Verifies {@link Profile} annotation functionality applied on method-level.
 */
public class MethodLevelProfileConfigurationTest {

    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = MethodLevelProfileConfiguration.class)
    @ActiveProfiles(profiles = "qa")
    public static class QaActiveProfileTest {

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext context;

        @Test
        public void shouldRegisterStartupAndShutdownInstants() {
            context.getBean("startupInstant", Instant.class);
            context.getBean("shutdownInstant", Instant.class);

            try {
                context.getBean("epochInstant", Instant.class);
                fail();
            } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
                // Legal to ignore.
            }
        }
    }

    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = MethodLevelProfileConfiguration.class)
    @ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"develop", "production"})
    public static class MethodProfileExpressionTest {

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext context;

        @Test
        public void shouldRegisterShutdownAndEpochInstants() {
            context.getBean("epochInstant", Instant.class);
            context.getBean("shutdownInstant", Instant.class);

            try {
                context.getBean("startupInstant", Instant.class);
                fail();
            } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
                // Legal to ignore.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Spring 5.1.2 version was tested.

Comment: It seems that it ONLY works at Configuration (class) level. I did some tests using this syntax at method level and it did not respected the conditions on spring 5.1.

Comment: @agodinhost Can you please look at the update section?

Comment: It seems that I used the wrong syntax - without the curly braces - I don't remember anymore. I'm actually using spring boot 2.1.1.RELEASE - it's not spring 5.1 as I said. These curly braces are annoying however it make sense - it's an expression, kinda short but an expression right?

Comment: @agodinhost It's an inline array, which follows standard Java syntax (e.g. look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154008/any-way-to-declare-an-array-in-line)).
BTW Spring Boot 2.1.1 RELEASE uses Spring 5.1.3

Comment: for some reason this syntax did not work for me: @Profile({"Tomcat & Linux"})
but this one did: @Profile({"Tomcat", "Linux"})
under spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: @PéterVeres `@Profile({"Tomcat", "Linux"})` means one of them (OR)

Comment: Got it to work in Kotlin with `@Profile(value = ["Tomcat & Linux"])`. It didn't work without the brackets.

Answer (score 17):

To load configuration only when **any of** multiple profiles are present use `@Profile` annotation as shown below:

```
@Profile({ "production", "preproduction" })
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {
    // code
}
```

To load configuration only when **all of** multiple profiles are present use `@Profile` annotation as shown below:

```
@Profile({ "production & preproduction" })
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {
    // code
}
```

To **NOT** load configuration when **any of** certain profiles are present use `@Profile` annotation as shown below:

```
@Profile({ "!production & !preproduction" })
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{environment.acceptsProfiles('Tomcat') && environment.acceptsProfiles('Linux')}")
```

Credits: Spring Source Code. Look up the @ConditionalOnExpression with your IDE then 'find usages' to see relevant examples within the source code. This will enable you to become a better developer.

Comment: does it accepts !(NOT) operator?

Answer (score 0):

The first profile is on the Top level.
The second I checked like this:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
final boolean isMyProfile = Arrays.stream(env.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch("MyProfile"::equals);
```