# When to specify multiple profiles for spring boot execution

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What is a typical use case for specifying multiple profiles *at runtime* for a Spring Boot application? I understand having different profiles for dev/int/qa/prod, etc. But when would it make sense to specify more than one profile when I run my SpringBoot app, e.g:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133808/spring-multiple-profiles-active) the examples show a Windows and a Unix profile, I guess multiple profiles can be useful where they are not mutually exclusive (like dev,int,qa,prod) but can instead be combined somehow together.