# How to initialise in Java a Map<String, String[]> object via the Collectors.toMap() method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, collectors

I want to initialize a `Map<String, String[]>` object in one logical line with the [Collectors.toMap() method](https://www.baeldung.com/java-initialize-hashmap#1-usingcollectorstomap) where I provide a stream of string tuples. Each tuple then is used via lambdas to fill the *key*  of a map entry with the first part of the tuple and to fill the first slot of the entry *values* with the second part of the tuple.

Because this sound complicated, here is the code I've tried so far:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = Stream.of(new String[][] {
  { "Hello", "World" }, 
  { "John", "Doe" }, 
}).collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> data[0], data -> [data[1]] ));
```

This is obviously syntacitially wrong. So the question is "How do I initialise  a `Map<String, String[]>` object via the `Collectors.toMap()` method? correctly

Comment: There is a typo, use `data -> data[1]` instead of `data -> [data[1]]`.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis No, that was intentional (although it _is_ a syntax error). Without the second brackets you go to `Map<String, String>` (which gives you a type error), because the left side of the equal sign asks for`Map<String, String[]>`

Comment: So please, edit the answer. It is really not clear what is the problem.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis The problem is how to initialise `Map<String, String[]>` via `Collectors.toMap`. I have edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: So you want each value of the map to be a string array with one string only?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, exactly! The map key come from the 1st part of the stream tuple and the 2nd part of the stream tuple is used for the one string in the map values array.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1154008/5133585) answer your question?

Comment: Do you want `Map<String, String[]> map = Stream.of(...).collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> data[0], data -> new String[] {data[1]}));`?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Yes, thank you. That's exactly it. I've tested it and it works perfectly. Thanks for "sticking with" my issue.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Do you want to make a answer out of this? If not, I'm happy do do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the desired output is `Map<String, String[]>`, then you have to instantiate the String array as a value in the `toMap` collector:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = Stream.of(
        new String[][] {
                { "Hello", "World" },
                { "John", "Doe" },
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                data -> data[0], 
                data -> new String[] {data[1]}));
```